# how to configure apache for xampp on mac osx lion to use mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, localhost

i am totally newbie for .htaccess or apache. Don't know how it works.

my url is like

`http://localhost/category.php?category=something`

i wanna get the variable value as ***something*** in category.php but wanna show the url as

`http://localhost/something`

how can i do this please help.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First rule will redirect the ugly URL to the pretty URL, second rule will internally redirect the pretty URL back while not changing what the user see on the browser URL:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect /category.php?category=something to /something
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+category\.php\?category=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L]

# Internally forward /something to /category.php?category=something
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ /category.php?category=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Once you confirm its working as expected change `R=302` to `R=301`.