# Pretty URL internally redirect to ugly URL

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Refer to that link: [how to configure apache for xampp on mac osx lion to use mod_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18948709/how-to-configure-apache-for-xampp-on-mac-osx-lion-to-use-mod-rewrite)
My question:

This helped me a lot, but what if link looks like this: http://localhost/category.php?category=something&id=2

How to change it to this:http://localhost/something/2 and that the second rule redirect pretty url back.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index.php\?([^&=]+)=([^&\ ]+)&([^&=]+)=([^&\ ]+)(\ |$) [NC] RewriteRule ^ /%2/%4/? [R=302,L].
```

I think this is it.

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ /category.php?category=$1&id=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

is not working. I have to rewrite ^(.+)/?$, but I don't know how.

My code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect /category.php?category=something to /something

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index\.php\?([^&=]+)=([^&\ ]+)
(\ |$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%2? [R=302,L]

# Internally forward /something to /category.php?category=something
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

# Redirect /category.php?category=something&id=ID to /something/ID
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index\.php\?([^&=]+)=([^&\ 
]+)&([^&=]+)=([^&\ ]+)(\ |$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%2\/%4/?  [R=302,L]

# Internally forward /something/ID to /category.php?category=something&id=ID
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: Note: the only time this is legitimate is if you're trying to migrate external links. I.e., you had ugly URLs before, which are already used on external sites, and you want to keep supporting those links without breaking them. In any other case you do not do this.